# mysql concat formatting to reverse concat second row interchanging fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Following is my query which is fetching concat value cards and `my_no` and storing to cards which is currently outputs:

> 123-5,009-1

I want to output like:

> 123-5,1-900

```php
->join('G_table', 'results.g_id', '=', 'G_table.id')
->select('G_table.g_name', DB::raw('group_concat(" ","[ ", cards,"-",my_no, " ] ") as cards'))
->whereDate('results.created_at', Carbon::yesterday())
->groupBy('G_table.g_name')
->get();
```

Comment: Why only 2nd group was reversed?

Comment: you have always two value only??

Comment: I'm always puzzled when I see concatenation function used in conjunction with application code.

Comment: I'm sending that output to VUeJs Axios call and there i was finding it confusing as value is not getting fetched in a array so printing that pattern of concat is difficult so need help on it ..

Answer (score 0):

if you have always 2 rows you could easyly manage the inversion in php frontend presentation

```
$myGroupConcat= "123-5,009-1";
$exp1 = explode(",", $myGroupConcat);
$exp2 = explode("-", $exp1[1]);
$exp1[1] = $exp2[1].'-'.$exp2[0];

$myGroupConcat = implode(",",$exp1);
```

Comment: i'm calling it inside VueJs Template ... if i call it inside php i can manage but getting puzzled at vue end so trying to get help on using concat output

Comment: i think is the more simple way . The code for string manipulation in SQL ...   ..   in really a lot more complex ..  and you can try using locate(), right() and on...

Comment: anyway   once you have obatined  your result in php you can loop over the resuy change the content of you field as suggeted  and after  encode the result.. ...

Comment: Yeah , figuring it out orelse will skip vu call and will use blade view - Thanks